# Maven build igonres code changes

Tags: java, git, maven, jar, build

I cloned a repo and did some code changes to one of my projects, but when i run mvn clean install and build the project the changes i've made to the code is not included and the jar is similar to the original jar without the changes.. Any thoughts on how to change this bizarre behavior or maven??

what i have done so far to resolve this..?

*I cleaned the /.m2 local repo with no luck

ran numerous mvn commands like mvn clean install -u but without any luck....

POM.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>apimgt</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>org.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.api</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>YYYY Management</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple.xoxo</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xxx.xxxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.xxx.xxxxx.registry.api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                        <Export-Package>
                            org.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.api.*;version="${version}",
                            org.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.api.model.xsd;version="${version}",
                        </Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>
                            *;resolution:=optional
                        </Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you run `mvn clean` separately?

Comment: what do you mean by "separately" ??

Comment: Instead of running `mvn clean install` try running `mvn clean` only.

Comment: just did the mvn clean and got a "build success" message but when i ran the "mvn install" and applied the jar the changes are still not visible

Comment: Please show the pom file.

Comment: @khmarbaise, see the edit

Comment: Where have you made changed ? in src/main/java?